# Read file in Python

Tags: python, file

I am new to Python and trying to learn the language structure.

I understand how `for` statement and `open` function work. But cannot explain how this piece of code works, which dumps the content of file sample_log.txt to screen:

```
for line in open("sample_log.txt"):
    print line
```

These are my questions:

1. Does `open` return a list?
2. When the file actually gets read to memory?
3. Does the file gets read line by line or all at once?

Comment: You should consider reading the documentation on [File Objects](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file-objects) and the [open()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#open) function!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `open` function returns a file object, they are iterable, so you can loop over it using a `for` expression.

Comment: Now I get it. So when the file get read and is it line by line or all at once?

Comment: @kamyar, line by line. This is good because it means you can easily process really big files without needing to load them into memory at once

Comment: @KamyarSouri you could also read the entire file in one time : http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects